# How to debug Jupyter Notebook profile_default/startup File?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kernel, ipython

I am placing a .py file in Jupyter Notebook profile_default/startup folder. It has some problems, I want to debug and see the logs. Is there any way I see the output or logs generated by that file. I am on windows 10. There are a few methods .py file. I am using keyboard module to generate a hotkey whenever the notebook starts. It isn't working for me. Please suggest a good way to at least debug that file. My ipykernel is 5.3.4 and ipython 7.16.1

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I've found so far is to fire up `ipython` from your console.

Assuming the error is not specific to how Jupyter starts the kernel, you will see the error with the stacktrace before the ipython shell starts.

If the error is specific to jupyter kernel, use `jupyter kernel`. It will start the kernel you specify, and drop a log line if there's an error.

Comment: Another way is to structure your startup scripts as ipython extension. It's actually quite easy. You can find an example in https://github.com/modelpredict/reliable-ipython-startup.

If you need more explanation, I've explained the setup and in-depth instructions on https://modelpredict.com/how-to-write-reliable-scripts-ipython/.